# RMI Remote connection fails

Tags: java, rmi

I have a very simple RMI server/client that works fine on the same machine. I'm trying to now execute the server on one machine and client on another both are on the same network. I've set the property to network ip using:

```
    System.getProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.x.x");
```

& disabled firewall on both machines but connection still fails.

Client code uses this to connect to server (the server uses createRegistry on 8888):

```
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.x.x",8888);
    ITest stub = (ITest) registry.lookup("ITest");
```

However the execption being caught seems to show an IP not the same as the one given eg 192.168.x.x vs 169.254.x.x:

```
Client exception: java.rmi.ConnectionException: Connection refused to host: 169.254.x.x; nested exception is ...
```

Comment: Do you have multiple physical or virtual network interfaces installed?

Comment: @Marged do you mean network adapters? Yeah there's 4 2 of which are virtual

Comment: `System.getProperty` does not set the property, and if you discard its return value does not do anything useful at all. After starting the server use netstat -p or lsof or similar depending on platform to check exactly what address and port it is listening on.

Comment: And you need to set it at the server JVM, and before exporting any remote objects, including the Registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dave_thompson_085 said I was calling `System.getProperty` which was a typo that I completely missed. Calling `System.setProperty` corrects this problem and now works.

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of reasons for this exception:

You have not started your rmiregistry in background.
You are trying to connect to the wrong port number.
Your firewall maybe blocking the connections.

Also make sure to check and disable any routers firewall restriction if any.

Comment: As far as I know LocateRegistery.createRegistry starts up service for me. The port number is correct in both server and client (8888). I've also disabled the firewall on both machines.

Comment: Not starting the Registry or using the wrong port number wil not cause this error.